# How can i take object from array which contain one element and it's and object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

this's my result of next function :

```
 db.collection('SOCIAL').get().then((snapshot) =>{
        snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
            dataNet.push(doc.data())
        })
        return dataNet
    })
```

i need to have these values as a temps, but i can't do these

Comment: What do you mean by "temps"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If by temps you mean that they are only "inside" your callback - then you can do something like this:

```
  const snapshot = await db.collection('SOCIAL').get();
  let dataNet = [];

  snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
    dataNet.push(doc.data())
  })

 // dataNet[0] is your object
```

Please note that you need to wrap this in an async function.

Comment: If  i put "await" i have an error(

Comment: what kind of error?